# How to find similar objects in a collection

Tags: c#, linq, find

I want to find similar objects in a collection depending on a **Method I implement**

for example this sample class:

```
class myObj
{
    public int Data1 { get; set; }

    public int Data2 { get; set; }

    public int Data3 { get; set; }        
}
```

then implement **Similar** method in the class:

```
public bool Similar(myObj obj)
{
    if (obj.Data1 == this.Data1 && obj.Data2 == this.Data2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

now I have this collection:

```
List<myObj> items = new List<myObj>();
// none similar
items.Add(new myObj() { Data1 = 1, Data2 = 2, Data3 = 4 });
items.Add(new myObj() { Data1 = 2, Data2 = 3, Data3 = 18 });
items.Add(new myObj() { Data1 = 3, Data2 = 4, Data3 = 75 });
items.Add(new myObj() { Data1 = 4, Data2 = 2, Data3 = 3 });
//similar
items.Add(new myObj() { Data1 = 5, Data2 = 26, Data3 = 97 });
items.Add(new myObj() { Data1 = 5, Data2 = 26, Data3 = 37 });
items.Add(new myObj() { Data1 = 10, Data2 = 45, Data3 = 47 });
items.Add(new myObj() { Data1 = 10, Data2 = 45, Data3 = 19 });
```

to get the similar objects I did this:

```
private static List<myObj> GetSimilars(List<myObj> items)
{
    List<myObj> similars = new List<myObj>();
    while (items.Count > 0)
    {
        var q = (from c in items
                 where c.Similar(items[0])
                 select c).ToList();

        if (q.Count > 1)
        {
            similars.AddRange(q);
            foreach (var obj in q)
                items.Remove(obj);
        }
        else
            items.Remove(items[0]);
    }    
    return similars;
}
```

is there a better way to do that?

Comment: It looks like you want to declare your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx which you can use in one of the numerous linq overloads

Comment: I can't use equals. I'm already using it somewhere else.

Comment: I don't mean override `Equals`, I mean implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` on some class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making this class, which is reusable.

```
public class MyObjSimilarity : EqualityComparer<myObj>
{
    public override bool Equals(myObj a, myObj b)
    {
        if (obj.Data1 == this.Data1 && obj.Data2 == this.Data2)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(myObj o)
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + o.Data1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + o.Data2.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

You could use like this,

```
var similarity = new MyObjSimilarity();
items.Where(o => similarity.Equals(o, w));
```

or pass into the constructor of a dictionary,

```
var similarity = new MyObjSimilarity();
var lookup = new Dictionary<myObj, string>(similarity);
```

or in a `GroupBy`

```
var similarity = new MyObjSimilarity();
items.GroupBy(o => o, o => o, similarity);
```

or like the other answer

```
var similarity = new MyObjSimilarity();
items.GroupBy(
    o => o,
    o => new { Instance = o, Count = Count(o) },
    similarity);
```

or in other framework friendly places.

Comment: cool answer !! but how about if i want them in groups. like @Tim Schmelter answer? I not saying that I wanted that from the start, but when I saw it I thought this is might be better.

Comment: @Star, there are many overloads for `GroupBy`, I've added one example.

Comment: another question: can I implement "Equals" externally? I mean if I changed the type and wanted the same thing.

Comment: @Star of course, but a common base type would have to expose the similar properties.

Comment: @Star, I'm not certain on the syntax of the last group by but you get the idea. It emminently doable.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
private static List<myObj> GetSimilars(List<myObj> items)
{
    return items.SelectMany(x => items.Where(z => x != z && x.Similar(z))).ToList();
}
```

or if you prefer this:

```
private static List<myObj> GetSimilars(List<myObj> items)
    {
        var result = from x in items
                     from y in items
                     where x != y && x.Similar(y)
                     select x;

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do that all with Linq's `GroupBy` and `SelectMany`:

```
var similarGroups = from i in items
                    group i by new { i.Data1, i.Data2 } into D1D2Group
                    where D1D2Group.Count() > 1
                    select D1D2Group;

foreach (var grp in similarGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("DataGroup:{0}/{1} Count:{2}"
               , grp.Key.Data1
               , grp.Key.Data2
               , grp.Count());
```

If you want to flatten the groups to a  `List<myObj>` like your `GetSimilars`:

```
 List <myObj> similars = similarGroups.SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return
    items.Where(w => items.Count(c => c.Similar(w)) > 1)
    /* add .Distinct() optional*/
    .ToList();
```

Comment: did you try this code? because it's not working. it have syntax error.

Comment: Tested it and worked on LinqPad... Post the syntax error i will correct it.

Comment: "'Key.myObj' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'Key.myObj' could be found". by the way what is key??

Comment: I think Key is your namespace... please verify you using my original code... This looks to me like you put the Count()-Method to an object auf myObj, be sure that your query the collection with Count()

Comment: I just copied and pasted. I've changed nothing. anyway I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

you could Implenent the Interface IComparable or use a self written comparer, which implements IComparer. If you do it this way, you can sort anny List of your object.

Here is a little tutorial:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727/en

Answer (score 1):

To account for the sideeffect in the example where the items list is being modified when calling GetSimilars you would have to do this. To get rid of the side effect loose the RemoveAll()

```
 private static List<myObj> GetSimilars(List<myObj> items)
 {
        var similars = from s in items
                 where items.Any(s2 => s != s2 && s.Similar(s2))
                 select s;

        items.RemoveAll(s => similars.Contains(s));

        return similars.ToList();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy to dothis,You can group the items based on their first and second values as follow...

```
var GroupByValues=items.GroupBy(obj=> new { val1 = obj.Data1,val2=obj.Data2 });
```

Then you can iterate through the group to get the values...